# Why did Phlox's mouth start to exhibit this behavior?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, star-trek-enterprise, actors

I've been watching [Star Trek: Enterprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Enterprise) and I noticed that, starting with Season 2, the left side of Dr. Phlox's mouth no longer moved correctly. I looked up the actor, [**John Billingsley**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Billingsley), to see if he had a stroke or something but didn't find anything.

I also wondered if he had nerve damage similar to Sylvester Stallone or Milo Ventaglia, but his mouth seemed normal during the first season. In an interview filmed several years after Enterprise, his mouth again seemed normal.

**Why did Phlox's mouth exhibit the behavior shown below, and was it due to a stroke or any kind of medical condition on the actor's part?**

[image]

Comment: Not posting as answer as have no solid evidence.

Most likely he had a case of Bells Palsy  -  When doing a search I did find some references to this but it did seem to just be speculation.  -  I would guess that unless somebody finds a comment from John himself this question will not be answerable.

Comment: This is opening weekend for the show's Season 1; https://intl.startrek.com/watch_video/john-billingsley-interview-part-i - He's doing it here as well.

Comment: Bell's palsy is also suggested as the most likely explanation here:  https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/2gpbf3/phloxs_mouth/

Comment: @Valorum - I went back and watched some S1 episodes. It's not as obvious there, but it does appear from time to time.